# Display interactive metrics within dbc.Card - Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm aiming to include interactive counts as metrics. Specifically, insert total sums within cards that will changed depending on the variable selected from a nav bar.

Using below, the Navbar is used to display the proportion of successes and failures as a pie chart. I want to use the corresponding sums of *success_count* and *failure_count* as a metric to be displayed as a number.

Is it possible to return these values and display them within the designated dbc.Card?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# This dataframe has 244 lines, but 4 distinct values for `day`
url="https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/spacex_launch_dash.csv"

spacex_df = pd.read_csv(url)

spacex_df.rename(columns={'Launch Site':'Site'}, inplace=True)

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

success_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Success Count", className="card-title"),
                html.P("###total count of successes", className="card-text"),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

failure_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Failure Count", className="card-title"),
                html.P("##total count of failures", className="card-text"),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("site-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id='Site', 
       value='Site', 
       options=[{'value': x, 'label': x} 
                for x in ['CCAFS LC-40', 'CCAFS SLC-40', 'KSC LC-39A', 'VAFB SLC-4E']],
       clearable=False
   ),
])


app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(success_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'pie-chart'), style={
                        "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    },),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert pie chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = "bar-chart")),
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(failure_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert bar chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph()),
            ], className="h-100"),
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)


@app.callback(
    Output("pie-chart", "figure"), 
    [Input("Site", "value")])

def generate_chart(value):
    pie_data = spacex_df[spacex_df['Site'] == value]
    success_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 0)
    failure_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 1)
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['success','failure'], values=[success_count, failure_count])])
    fig.update_layout(title=f"Site: {value}")
    
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `html.Div` in your card with id and then return `html.P` in this Div. Something as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# This dataframe has 244 lines, but 4 distinct values for `day`
url="https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/spacex_launch_dash.csv"

spacex_df = pd.read_csv(url)

spacex_df.rename(columns={'Launch Site':'Site'}, inplace=True)

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

success_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Success Count", className="card-title"),
                html.Div(id='count_of_success'),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

failure_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Failure Count", className="card-title"),
                html.Div(id='count_of_failure'),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("site-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id='Site', 
       value='Site', 
       options=[{'value': x, 'label': x} 
                for x in ['CCAFS LC-40', 'CCAFS SLC-40', 'KSC LC-39A', 'VAFB SLC-4E']],
       clearable=False
   ),
])


app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(success_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'pie-chart'), style={
                        "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    },),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert pie chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = "bar-chart")),
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(failure_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert bar chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph()),
            ], className="h-100"),
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)


@app.callback(
    [Output("pie-chart", "figure"),
    Output("count_of_success", "children"),
    Output("count_of_failure", "children")], 
    [Input("Site", "value")])

def generate_chart(value):
    pie_data = spacex_df[spacex_df['Site'] == value]
    success_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 0)
    failure_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 1)
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['success','failure'], values=[success_count, failure_count])])
    fig.update_layout(title=f"Site: {value}")
    
    return fig, html.P(f'###total count of successes are: {success_count}'), html.P(f'###total count of failure are: {failure_count}')

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I'm not getting any text or numbers in the cards?

Comment: @jonboy: Can you try to change port to new one?

Comment: Yeh tried this but same output

Comment: @jonboy: Hm it’s quite strange. It’s working well for me. Did you run my code or revise your code with my suggestion?

Comment: Got it going, just added a className to the card and it worked for some reason. Thankyou